# JAVA graphics button

Tags: java, jbutton

I have created a matrix on java and I need to add two `JButton` "cancel" and "submit" below the matrix 
This is my code but it miss the two JButton , need your help please .

```
public class matrice2 extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final int width;
private final int height;

private final JLabel[] horizon;
private final JLabel[] vertical;
private final JButton[][] centre;
//private final JButton[] VC;

private final ImageIcon ZERO = new ImageIcon("0.jpg");
private final ImageIcon ONE = new ImageIcon("1.jpg");

public matrice2(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    horizon = new JLabel[width];
    vertical = new JLabel[height];
    centre = new JButton[width][height];

    initFrame();
    fillContent();

    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void initFrame() {
    this.setSize(700, 700);
    this.setTitle("Matrice du graphe");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private JLabel createColumnHeader(int x) {
    horizon[x] = new JLabel("H" + (x + 1));
    return horizon[x];
}

private JLabel createRowHeader(int y) {
    vertical[y] = new JLabel("V" + (y + 1));
    return vertical[y];
}

private JButton createCell(int x, int y) {
    centre[x][y] = new JButton();
    centre[x][y].addActionListener(new MatriceListener(this,x,y));
    return centre[x][y];
}

public void fillContent() {

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(width+2, height+2));

    this.add(new JLabel());

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        this.add(createColumnHeader(x));

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        this.add(createRowHeader(y));
        for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
            this.add(createCell(x,y));


    }

}

public void setIcon(int x, int y) {
    centre[x][y].setIcon(ONE);
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt and explain the issues you had trying to implement it

Answer (score 1):

**Change the `fillContent()` method:**

```
public void fillContent() {

    JPanel content = new JPanel();

    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(width + 2, height + 2));

    content.add(new JLabel());

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        content.add(createColumnHeader(x));
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        content.add(createRowHeader(y));
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            content.add(createCell(x, y));
        }

    }
    add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.add(new JButton("Submit"));
    buttons.add(new JButton("Cancel"));

    add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```